# Консольное приложение. Ограничение ввода символов пользователем с помощью методов ReadLine() и Read()

Tags: c#, консоль

Задача стоит в том, чтобы ограничить ввод пользователя и чтобы ограничение работало в созданной переменной. Создаем переменную в которую будет помещаться вводимое пользователем число (четырехзначное), при вводе пользователем числа работают клавиши удаления,  перемещения (влево, вправо), цифры, все остальное игнорируется, производится ограничение ввода до 4 цифр(включая 4ю). Далее число 
должно посимвольно сравнивается с 4хзначным числом которое генерируется компьютером, застрял на том что если использовать пример с :
 `ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true); ...`
то в консоль можно вбивать что угодно. 
 А если методы и переменные не использовать, то запрет на ввод символов перечисленных выше действует. Не знаю как это все связать и лучше использовать массив char или брать int массив.Так же, как ограничить ввод по количеству? То есть что бы пользователь мог ввести только 4 цифры. Огромная просьба, если есть возможность расписать все как можно подробнее, я еще мал в данном деле и хочу максимально разобраться в данном вопросе, ничего в голову не приходит... .

Пример 1 :

```
public static void Valid()
{

    ConsoleKeyInfo key ;

    while (true)
    {
        key = Console.ReadKey(true);

        if (char.IsDigit(key.KeyChar))
        {
            Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
        }

        else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            Console.Write(key.KeyChar + " " + key.KeyChar);
        }
    }
}
```

Пример 2 : Это всего лишь начальный набросок.

```
    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
    char[] inq = new char[] { (char)Console.Read() };

    if (char.IsDigit(inq[0]))
    {
        key = Console.ReadKey(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < inq.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(inq[0]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получился такой метод, вроде работает корректно, проверяйте:

```
static int GetValue()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4);
    int curStart = Console.CursorLeft;
    int curOffset = 0;
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
    do
    {
        keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (char.IsDigit(keyInfo.KeyChar) && sb.Length < 4)
        {
            sb.Insert(curOffset, keyInfo.KeyChar);
            curOffset++;
            Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
        }
        if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow && curOffset > 0) curOffset--;
        if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow && curOffset < sb.Length) curOffset++;
        if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && curOffset > 0)
        {
            curOffset--;
            sb.Remove(curOffset, 1);
            Console.CursorLeft = curStart;
            Console.Write(sb.ToString().PadRight(4));
        }
        if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Delete && curOffset < sb.Length)
        {
            sb.Remove(curOffset, 1);
            Console.CursorLeft = curStart;
            Console.Write(sb.ToString().PadRight(4));
        }
        Console.CursorLeft = curStart + curOffset;
    }
    while (!(keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter && sb.Length > 0));
    Console.WriteLine();
    return int.Parse(sb.ToString());
}
```

Самое сложное здесь - поддержка перемещения курсора влево-вправо, без нее было бы гораздо проще.

Добавил на всякий случай поддержку `Delete` - это довольно просто, т.к. отличие от `Backspace` только в том, что курсор не перемещается.

Comment: Очень помогли, но к сожалению для меня как для начинающего осталось много непонятных деталей в коде к примеру:  Что делает число 4 в созданном обьекте StringBuilder (     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4);  ) 
И таких вопросов по коду много, могли бы вы прокомментировать ваш код как можно подробнее? Буду весьма признателен.

Comment: Это начальное значение "вместительности" строки, так как мы знаем максимальный размер - выгоднее указать его заранее. Какие еще вопросы?