# Запретить ввод в консоль

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь заблокировать ввод с клавиатуры в консоль, для этого использую метод:

```
public static string ReadDigitsFromConsole()
{
  while (true)
  {
    string result = "";
    switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
    {
       case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
       if (result.Length > 0)
       {
          result = result.Remove(startIndex: result.Length - 1, count: 1);
          Console.Write(value: $"{Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar} {Console.ReadKey(intercept: true).KeyChar}");
       }
       break;
       case ConsoleKey.Enter:
       Console.WriteLine();
        return result;
      default:
        if (char.IsDigit(c: Console.ReadKey(intercept: true).KeyChar))
         {
           Console.Write(value: Console.ReadKey(intercept: true).KeyChar);
           result += Console.ReadKey(intercept: true).KeyChar;
         }
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Но при вызове в

```
private static void Main() 
{ 
   ReadDigitsFromConsole(); 
   ...
   Console.Read();
}
```

Консольное приложение просто висит и ничего не происходит, другие методы не выполняются.
Как можно запустить его в отдельном потоке?

Comment: Так вопрос в том как запускать отдельные потоки или как запрещать ввод с клавиатуры? Или проблема в том  что зависло консольное приложение?

Comment: @V.March, В принципе всё вместе :) Вообще тема: как запрещать ввод с клавиатуры

Comment: Не надо запрещать ввод в консоль, достаточно перестать с консоли что то считывать. Уберите все ваши `Console.ReadXXX()` и никто в кнсоль ничего не введет.

Comment: А это не вы спрашивали: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/750027/218063 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидная проблема вашего кода — постоянный повторный вызов `Console.ReadKey`. Дело в том, что каждый вызов `Console.ReadKey` ожидает ввода *нового* символа из консоли. Поэтому, например, код

```
if (char.IsDigit(c: Console.ReadKey(intercept: true).KeyChar))
{
   Console.Write(value: Console.ReadKey(intercept: true).KeyChar);
   result += Console.ReadKey(intercept: true).KeyChar;
}
```

ожидает в худшем случае трёх дополнительных нажатий на клавиши.

Думаю, имеет смысл на самом деле использовать запоминать введённую клавишу во временной переменной. А также вынести определение переменной `result` за цикл (а то значение сбрасывается на каждой итерации):

```
public static string ReadDigitsFromConsole()
{
    string result = "";
    while (true)
    {
        var k = Console.ReadKey(true);
        switch (k.Key)
        {
        case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
            if (result.Length > 0)
            {
                result = result.Remove(startIndex: result.Length - 1, count: 1);
                Console.Write(value: $"{k.KeyChar} {k.KeyChar}");
            }
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.Enter:
            Console.WriteLine();
            return result;
        default:
            if (char.IsDigit(c: k.KeyChar))
            {
                Console.Write(value: k.KeyChar);
                result += k.KeyChar;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```